# The importance of AGT level in trace file in NS2

Tags: networking, routes, protocols, simulation, ns2

Vector based forward is one of the routing protocols for underwater wireless sensor networks. To run it you want an aqua-sim package for NS2.
I want calculate the delay, overhead, and packet delivery ratio.
The problem is: When I run it, it don't show the AGT in the trace file for this protocol, and all the awk codes in internet uses AGT to calculate anything they want.
I want a help for what the AGT level and why it must use for calculate delay for example.
And I want a help how to show the AGT level in the trace file although I am turned it on in tcl file for this protocol.

Comment: »»delay, overhead, and packet delivery ratio«« : There are ~240 scipts. (So far I haven't found good ones for those data.) Usually successful with aquasim is APP-Tool : **1**. http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html ... **2**. 
https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool . ... **Perl and AWK** scripts https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing